# Сравнение элементов 2 массивов PHP

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо сравнить 2 массива и вывести на экран "test", если элементы 1 массива не содержат элементы похожие на элементы второго.

```
// Есть массив №1, который содержит полный URL фотографий, которые будут выданы пользователю.

$array1 = array(
    "http://vk.com/photo-30666517_315641240",
    "http://vk.com/photo-63314435_318050082"
);

// Есть массив №2, который содержит неполный URL фотографий, которые пользователь УЖЕ посмотрел.

$array2 = array(
    "photo-130666517_315641240",
    "photo-163314435_318050082"
);

// То есть, фактически, эти массивы совпадают, то есть, показывать пользователю фотографии не нужно.

// Создадим массив №3, который необходимо заполнить, если есть фотографии, который пользователь ЕЩЕ НЕ посмотрел.

$array3 = array();

foreach($array1 as $value) {
    foreach($array2 as $val) {
        if(strpos($value, $val)) {
            $array3[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array3);
```

Однако, в данном случае "test" выведется 2 раза.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так что-ли ?

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "http://vk.com/photo-30666517_315641240",
    "http://vk.com/photo-63314435_318050082"
);
$array2 = array(
    "photo-30666517_315641240",
    "photo-163314435_318050082"
);
$out=array();
 foreach($array2 as $val) {
    foreach($array1 as $value) {
        if(strpos($value, $val)) {
           continue 2;
        }
    }
        $out[]=$value;
 }
 print_r($out);
```

http://ideone.com/jZx1wk
или http://ideone.com/51KjK8 если вам  нужно наоборот...

Comment: @eicto, спасибо, но, выводит "test" 1 раз, хотя, оба значения в массивах совпадают.

Comment: так вам надо один или два раза ?

Comment: в смысле вам нужно вывести "test" если ни разу не совпало ? т.е. в данном случае не вывести test ?

Comment: @eicto, тьфу, я уже сам запутался. В общем, попробую чуть точнее объяснить: допустим, мы имеем в первом массиве 2 фотографии, во втором 3, необходимо сравнить элементы, если найдены фотографии, в которых нет совпадения с первым, то записать это в новый массив.

Comment: Emice  посмотрите мой ответ, я полагаю работает все, так как Вам нужно.

Comment: @Emice, какое это отношение имеет к вопросу заданному в начале ???

Comment: вот исправил, если вы ещё раз поменяете условия, то попадете в в специальный ад.

Comment: @eicto, спасибо Вам, простите за неправильное объяснение. ^)

Answer (score 0):

**Исправлено не просмотренные фотографии пишутся в массив**

```
    $array1 = array(
    "http://vk.com/photo-30666517_315641240",
    "http://vk.com/photo-63314435_318050082",
    "http://vk.com/НЕ СМОТРЕЛ"
);
$array2 = array(
    "photo-30666517_315641240",
    "photo-63314435_318050082",
);
$a_dont_look = array();// В массив запишется все что не было просмотрено
foreach($array1 as $all_photo){
    $is_look = false; // По умолчанию фото не просматривалось
    foreach($array2 as $look){
        if(strpos($all_photo, $look)) { // Если хоть одно фото было просмотрено
        $is_look = true; 
break;

        }
    }
    if(!$is_look ){ // Если ни одной фотки не было просмотрено
        $a_dont_look[] = $all_photo;
    }

}
print_R($a_dont_look);
```

Comment: @zsiteru, спасибо за Ваш ответ, видимо я очень плохо объяснил ситуацию. Я сделал комментарии, просьба посмотреть: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fc33dc495cfc6f4e53879ce648513d3ad1029a0